# Authenticate on stateProvider for a specific user (angular-fullstack)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-fullstack

I use angular-fullstack generator for my project(https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) and I have a demand page on my website who needs to be accessible by users with a defined role(admin).
This page also needs to be accessible by the user who has created the demand.

I know that I can put authenticate:true on my state provider to authorize only the authenticated users but I need a more precise system for my situation because I need to allow only users with a specific role or a specific user id.

Is there a way to manage this case in the stateProvider or must I be doing this in my page controller, after the $state redirection?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorization for specific `role` can be done but you need to modify some code.

Add a new field `access` to your `state` configuration file as follows. Let's store the `authRequiredFor` array in that which contain the roles which require authorization to access that particular state `myState`.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('myState', {
        url: '...',
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: '...',
        access: {
            authRequiredFor: ['role1', 'role2']
        }                
    });
});
```

In your `app.js` file in the `run()` function, you need to add and modify the `$stateChangeStart` callback function to check whether the user needs authentication or not before accessing any state.

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth, $state) {
    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
            if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
                $location.url('/login');
            }
            if (next.access) {  // check if the state config contains the field `access`
                var permissions = next.access;
                var userRole = Auth.getCurrentUser().role;
                if (permissions.authRequiredFor) {
                    // check if the logged in user's role matches with the roles in the array
                    if (permissions.authRequiredFor.indexOf(userRole) >= 0) {
                        $location.url('/login'); // or redirect him to some other url/state
                    }
                }
            }        
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this solves the issue.